# @SuppressWarnings Annotated parameter qualification rules

Tags: java

When I look at SuppressWarnings.java, I see that the parameter limit for this annotation is String[], but why do we usually write this like this? (Example: @SuppressWarnings({"ratypes", "unchecked"})),[] can also store data of type String, why not follow the requirements of ["ratypes", "unchecked"]?

```
    @SuppressWarnings({"ratypes", "unchecked"})
    protected static Set copy(Set set){
        Set copySet = new LinkedHashSet(set);
        return copySet;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to initialise an array in Java is to enclose it in curly braces. e.g.

```
String[] x = {"as", "as"};
```

---

Thus, when you type

> @SuppressWarnings({"ratypes", "unchecked"})

you are essentially creating a new String[] for the input to the annotation.

Comment: i see, thank you very much ! I am confused for a long time.